# ember.js with MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, ember.js, localhost

I am trying to work out for a small `ember` application. What I want is to do is list all the items from a table of the MySQL DB. I am able to retrive and display the data from the `localStorage` of the `ember store` but I do not know how can I implement same thing using MySQL Database.

Any kind of help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do it, but basically you need some sort of server-side API to handle actually querying the MySQL database and returning data. This is usually done these days with a [REST API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) using the interchange format [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Whether you use PHP, Node, or another server technology, there are a couple of ways you can pull the data into Ember. Let's assume your have a server-side method called search, which returns a JSON array of blog posts, something like:

```json
[
  {"title": "blog post 1", "body": "this is a blog post"},
  {"title": "blog post 2", "body": "this is another post"}
]
```

The easiest way to pull this data into Ember would be a simple ajax call:

```js
var IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function()
  {
    return $.getJSON("http://apiurl.com/search");
  }
});
```

In the above Ember route definition, the model is set to a function which returns the promise object returned by the JQuery getJSON method.

The template might look something like this:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
{{#each}}
  {{title}}<br/>
  {{description}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Many Ember users choose to use [EmberData](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/) instead of a ajax calls, however, that part of Ember is still under development and I found I had an easier time building my application without EmberData. Check out this article from one of the co-founders of Discourse:

http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html

The Ember Guides are pretty good place to start:

http://emberjs.com/guides/
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Dreamfactory](http://www.dreamfactory.com/) It's a SaaS REST API that will connect to a variety of SQL and NoSQL backends. I use it with SQL Server running on an RDS instance and haven't had any issues. I have written a super-basic, WIP [Ember-Data adapter](https://github.com/ultimatemonty/ember-data-dreamfactory-adapter) for it. It still needs a TON of work but is mostly functional.